# On loading .obj material make blurr

Tags: android, rajawali

I am loading .obj file with material file.

I have scale down my .obj like below

```
mObjectGroup.setScale(.01f);
```

In Blender it is rendered perfect fine, but when i render it using rajawali some material get blurred.

In Blender it lloks like it
[image]

And in android after rendering images get blurred.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I recall using .obj with materials is a mess! Try exporting as FBX or any other format

Comment: But i am using Rajawali Lib which s taking .obj so i am tring to load .obj

Comment: i really dont even know anything named like that! but have a look here they have some tutorials https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali

Comment: Yes.. I have looked very thoroughly .. in fact working on it from last 1 month...